# Find out the client workspace specification of a workspace which was synced by a different perforce client (different user)

Tags: perforce

I'm confused about what exactly does perforce client mean and how does it maintain the information of the synced files (for eg: mapping of local files to perforce depot).

Lets say a person A synced some files from perforce depot to his client workspace. Those files exists on his local system which are then transferred to me over a network into my local system.

If I run `p4 client` on the workspace that I just got, what will be the output? Does it give me the client specification of person A's workspace?.

Does perforce client maintain the client specification as a file in the workspace itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Perforce "client spec" (usually "client" for short) is an entity in the server database that tracks the state of a specific client workspace.  Each client host should have its own client spec (or possibly many client specs, with each mapping a different folder on that host's local filesystem).  Other than the form that describes the client spec (what you see when you run `p4 client -o`, which is derived from information in the db.domain and db.views tables), the client spec also comprises database entries that describe each individual file that is synced to the workspace (db.have), each file that is currently open in a pending changelist (db.working and db.locks), and any pending or completed "resolve" operations for those files (db.resolve and db.resolved).

If person A sends you files from his workspace, no Perforce-specific information is encoded within those files, because that information is maintained on the server and is stored relative to person A's client spec.  Once the workspace files are removed from the context of a Perforce workspace, they no longer have any connection to Perforce or their version history in the depot; they're just files.  (If you use tools like Dropbox or Google Drive, think about it like a file you remove from your Dropbox folder and then email to someone as an attachment which they save to their own desktop -- they have the file, but it's not synced with your Dropbox any more.)

If you run `p4 client` after receiving those files, it is in no way associated with the files themselves.  Instead you will view (or create) your own client spec for the server that you're connected to per your local `P4PORT` and `P4CLIENT` values.  If these values are unset, you will be attempting to connect to a server at `perforce:1666` with a client spec name that matches your local hostname.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You are the same person who answered my question two months ago.